# TinyMCE only allow images from whitelisted domains or only allow upload

Tags: tinymce

is there a way in TinyMCEs image plugin to only allow images from a whitelist of domains?

Or is it possible to remove the option of inserting an image url entirely and only show the "upload" tab?

Thanks in advance.